# How to analyse CTS verifier results?

Tags: cts

After running the verifier app in device i get a result in .xml format which is not that friendly to analyze the results. Is there any tool to analyze this result like CTS automation tool generates?

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool to verify the generated `.xml` from CTS Verifier.

Things we can do is to check if any part is not executed in the generated XML. The `.xml` is just a display of what we perform manually in CTS Verifier.

```
such as checking for an executed case in .xml ie Pass or Fail:
<test title="Camera FOV Calibration" class-  name="com.android.cts.verifier.camera.fov.PhotoCaptureActivity" result="*pass*">

<test title="Streaming Video Quality Verifier" class-name="com.android.cts.verifier.streamquality.StreamingVideoActivity" result="fail" />

The Untested combinations will be displayed Under :
Untested combinations:
<Will display if Not tested/Not Executed>
```

Answer (score -1):

How to analyze CTS verifier results?

Install CTS Verifier in your device.. Lanuch CTS verifier , connect your device in PC or Laptop , run the adb command .